# How to achieve no gap between QLineEdit and QLineEdit in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

In the case I added two QLineEdits with a horizontal layout. The style of QLineEdit is set to only the top and bottom borders. But there is a gap between the top and bottom borders of the two qlabels. How can I make the top and bottom borders of the two QLineEdits together without gaps?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Edit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Edit, self).__init__()
        self.setText(text)
        self.setFixedSize(200, 40)
        self.setStyleSheet("""*{border-width: 1px;
                                    border-style: solid;
                                    border-color: red;
                                    border-left:none;
                                    border-right:none;
                                    margin:0px;
                                    padding:0px;
                                    }""")


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        h = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        a = Edit("Hello World")
        b = Edit("Hello World")
        h.addWidget(a)
        h.addWidget(b)
        h.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        h.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(h)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could show an image of what you get and what you want to get in order to understand you

Comment: You have set the edit box to height 40.  Decreasing that will decrease the gap - is that what you are looking for?  You could just delete the setFixedSize statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding, you want to effectively make your Edit widgets appear as one with no gap between them?

Your `QHBoxLayout` has a default value for spacing that is used to add a gap between widgets. You're clearing the `contentsMargins` (the margin space used around the edge of the layout) but the between-widget spacing will still be there as dictated by your current style.

Add a `setSpacing(0)` to clear it:

```py
def initUI(self):
    h = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    a = Edit("Hello World")
    b = Edit("Hello World")
    h.addWidget(a)
    h.addWidget(b)
    h.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    h.setSpacing(0)
    h.addStretch(1)
    self.setLayout(h)
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
    self.show()
```